# How to rewrite a mysql_query to mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting this error `Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in.... The problem is that i dont know how i rewrite a mysql query to mysqli.

I need help to rewrite this line:

```
 $run_sql_request1 = mysql_query($sql_request1) or die("The system cannot select the news");
```

Comment: Yes: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: exactly what it says 'use mysqli or PDO instead"